# How to use Switch in JSON Schema 6 with multiple IFs

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have entity which is of array. I want to call different entity types based on a property called dataStoreType. My Schema looks like this:

```
"entities":{
  "type":"array",
  "switch":[
    {
      "if": {"properties":{"dataStoreType":"RELATIONAL"}},
      "then":{"$ref": "#/definitions/entities-relational"}
    },
    {
      "if": {"properties":{"dataStoreType":"DOCUMENT"}},
      "then":{"$ref": "#/definitions/entities-no-sql"}
    },
    {
      "if": {"properties":{"dataStoreType":"KEYVALUE"}},
      "then":{"$ref": "#/definitions/entities-key-value"}
    }
  ]
}
```

My instance JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "document-simple",
    "dataStoreType": "RELATIONAL",
    "entities": [
        {
            "name": "Employee",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "firstName",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "required": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "lastName",
                    "type": "STRING"
                },
        }
    ]
}
```

But my Schema is not validating this instance correctly because I think there is some error in the switch. I am sure that JSON is not being validated because I have defined other rules for entities(which I have not mentioned) and when my instance violates that, the schema is not showing error.

What could be the error in my switch

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that where you have:

```
"properties": {"dataStoreType": "RELATIONAL"}
```

what you actually need is:

```
"properties": {"dataStoreType": {"const": "RELATIONAL"}}
```

Beyond that, note that `switch` is no longer a JSON Schema proposal, but `if`/`then`/`else` has been accepted for the next draft (draft-07).  So when using Ajv or another validator with early `if` support turned on, or moving to draft-07 when it is out and supported, you want:

```
"entities":{
  "type":"array",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "if": {"properties":{"dataStoreType":{"const":"RELATIONAL"}}},
      "then":{"$ref": "#/definitions/entities-relational"}
    },
    {
      "if": {"properties":{"dataStoreType":{"const":"DOCUMENT"}}},
      "then":{"$ref": "#/definitions/entities-no-sql"}
    },
    {
      "if": {"properties":{"dataStoreType":{"const":"KEYVALUE"}}},
      "then":{"$ref": "#/definitions/entities-key-value"}
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the equivalent of a switch (without fall-through) or a chained set of else-ifs (which also works, but gets harder to read the more you chain).

Your `if` conditions are mutually exclusive, so `oneOf` is appropriate here and will do what you want.

I would definitely avoid using `switch`, as it has been pretty thoroughly rejected as a proposal for the standard.  It is unlikely to ever be added.

Comment: With "xeipuuv/gojsonschema" oneOf does not work for me, because then is validated only when if condition is valid. And as they are mutually exclusive, only one then is validated, all the rest are not, so they become valid, but oneOf requires only one schema to be valid. anyOf works fine. Don't know if this gojsonschema behaviour is according to standart.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, anyOf will be wrong too, because of false negatives. (It will make JSONs that are not valid valid).

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema Draft 6 does not support the `"if"` and `"then"` keywords. It is [currently a proposal](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/180). Probably you use an implementation which already supports it (ajv, maybe?).

On the other hand you can achieve what you want using `"oneOf"` and `"const"` in the following way:

```
{
    "oneOf" : [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "dataStoreType": {
                    "const": "RELATIONAL"
                },
                "entities": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {    
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/entities-relational"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "dataStoreType": {
                    "const": "DOCUMENT"
                },
                "entities": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {    
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/entities-no-sql"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        // and here comes the KEYVALUE schema.. I think you get it now
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I am getting error: 1 subschema matched out of 2. My JSON  has following structure:
'{
 "name": "document-simple",
 "dataStoreType":"RELATIONAL",
 "entities": [
  {
   "namea": "Employee",
   "attributes": [
    {
     "name": "firstName",
     "type": "STRING",
     "required": true
    },
    {
     "name": "lastName",
     "type": "STRING"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}'

Comment: maybe you used allOf instead of oneOf ?